# Rootless docker run -u $CURRENT_USER however mounts still mounted as root

Tags: docker, jenkins, mounted-volumes, rootless

I'm trying to set up our Jenkins instance to run docker containers rootless.

When jenkins starts the container, the `-u` is flag is passed with the id of the jenkins runner.

The runner is named "**runner**" and has UID **3217** and thus Jenkins executes:
`docker run -u 3217:100 -v /opt/build/agent/job/:/opt/build/agent/job:rw,z image`

The first thing jenkins does, from inside the container:

`touch /opt/build/agent/job/jenkins.log` however this results in a prompt *`Permission denied`*.

When I bash into the container and run `id`:

> uid=3217 gid=100(users) groups=100(users)

is returned (which is expected). Additionally, when I run `ls -la /opt/build/agent/job` all files and directories are owned by root:

[image]

This is in contrast to when I exit out of the container and, as the `runner` user, run the  `ls -la` against the mount point, where every file is owned by `runner:users` and thus can easily be manipulated from outside the container, by the same user.

I'm unable to remove the `-u` argument from Jenkins, and I'm at a loss at how to mitigate this issue.

Is there any way for docker to mount the directories with the same permissions specified with the `-u` argument?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way for docker to mount the directories with the same permissions specified with the -u argument?

No. Docker does not change any permissions.

The directory has the permissions that it has. If the directory does not exist, it will be created by dockerd process, which runs as root, so the directory will be owned by root.

If you want the directory to have different permissions, create the directory yourself, or `chmod` it.

If you do not want the directory to be autocreted as root, you can use `--mount type=bind,source=/opt/build/agent/job/,target=/opt/build/agent/job,bind-propagation=shared,rw`, but I have no idea about selinux then.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, the mounted directory already exists on the host os with the permissioned shown in the image above. I'm at a loss why those permissions are not transferred to the container.

Comment: I believe permissions are not transferred to the container is as expected. Otherwise rootless container always have power to modify files from Host,  this will be a large security risk.